# Prolog membership operation on a list which returns the index of the found element

Tags: functional-programming, prolog

I have currently started with PROLOG and I want to write a predicate which checks if a given object is in this list or not. If the object is in the list the predicate should return the index of the element. If the element is not found it should return 0.

It should work like this: `find(3,[1,4,5,3,2,3],N). -> yes. N / 4`
`find(2,[1,3,4,5,6,7],N). -> yes. N / 0`

But I have problems with counting up the index N and maybe someone here can help.  I've seen many different ways on how to traverse a list but I found so many different ways and I wasn't able to understand how they work. I would be really happy if someone can provide a solution and explain how it works and why.

This is what I wrote so far:

```
find(X, [X|TAIL], N) :- N is 1, write(N).
find(X, [], N) :- N is 0, write(N).

find(X, [_|TAIL], N) :- find(X, TAIL, N + 1).
```

It is working for the basecases:

```
find(a, [a, b, c, d, e, f, g], N) -> yes. N / 1.
find(j, [a, b, c, d, e, f, g], N) -> yes. N / 0.
```

But when it is starting with recursion It is not working anymore and I don't understand what's going wrong.

For the recursion case it gives me this:  `find(b, [a, b, c, d, e, f, g], N) -> no.`

I am thankful for every answer and every comment!

### Requirements:

- If an element is not in the list it should output `yes. N = 0.` Examples: `?- find(a, [], N) -> yes. N = 0.` and `?- find(a, [b,c,d], N) -> yes. N = 0.`
- If an element is in the list it should output the index of that element (start counting with 1). Examples: `?- find(a, [a, b, c], N) -> yes. N = 1` and `?- find(a, [b,c,a,d], N) -> yes. N = 3.`
- If there is the element more than one time it should only output the index of the first appearance of the element. Example: `?- find(a, [a,b,c,a], N) -> yes. N = 1.`
- It should always only give on answer.
- If possible no libraries should be used.
- The query `?- find(a, [a, b,c], 0)` and `?- find(a, [b, a, c], 0)` and every other query where a is in the list should be answered with `no`.
- The query `?- find(a, [a, b, c, a], 4)` should be answered with `no` because the a with index 4 is not the first apperance of a.

Comment: I made a little bit of progress: 

``find(X, [], 0).
  find(X,[X|_], 1).
  find(X, [_|Xs], N) :- find(X, Xs, Rest), N is 1 + Rest.``

This code is now working for elements that are in the list, but if I want to find an object that is not in the list, N is becoming 6 and not 0. How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: What should happen with `find(a, [a,b,c,a,b,c], Index)` ? First result `1`, on backtracking `4`, on backtracking again `0` for not found is what my code does, but I don't know if that makes good sense or not.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler I am not quite sure if I understand you correctly. But with `find(a, [a,b,c,a,b,c], Index)` Prolog should give the following answer: `Yes. Index = 1`. So it should return the index of the first appearance of the given atom. If the atom is not appearing in the list it should give 0. 

Thank you for your comment!

Comment: This is known as `nth/3` or `nth1/3`, but without this `0`-case.

Comment: Is there a good reason for the "return 0" part of this question (which is rather ugly from a Prolog relational view)? Wouldn't simple failure be sufficient? `nth1/3` already exists - https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=nth1/3

Comment: @brebs I've just started learning PROLOG and of course a simple `no` would be a good answer if an element is not in the list. I simply wanted to try things out and learn a little bit so that I can understand the recursion better. So there is no real reason why this should be better than a simple `no` it was just for me to understand PROLOG a little bit better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the argument order of `nth1/3`

```
nth1_once_else_0(Nth1, Lst, Elem) :-
    nth1_once_else_0_when_(Lst, Elem, 1, Nth1).

nth1_once_else_0_thaw_([H|_], Elem, Upto, Nth1) :-
    Upto == Nth1,
    !,
    H = Elem.   
nth1_once_else_0_thaw_(L, _Elem, _Upto, Nth1) :-
    L == [],
    !,
    Nth1 = 0.
nth1_once_else_0_thaw_(L, Elem, _Upto, Nth1) :-
    Nth1 == 0,
    !,
    nth1_once_else_0_thaw_0_(L, Elem).
nth1_once_else_0_thaw_(_L, _Elem, Upto, Nth1) :-
    % If gone past Nth1, fail
    nonvar(Nth1),
    Nth1 =< Upto,
    !,
    fail.
nth1_once_else_0_thaw_([H|T], Elem, Upto, Nth1) :-
    (   nonvar(Nth1),
        Nth1 > Upto -> true
    ;   H \= Elem
    ),
    !,
    % Elements must be different
    dif(H, Elem),
    Upto1 is Upto + 1,
    nth1_once_else_0_when_(T, Elem, Upto1, Nth1).
nth1_once_else_0_thaw_([H|_], Elem, Upto, Nth1) :-
    ?=(H, Elem),
    % Able to compare
    H = Elem,
    !,
    % Elements match
    Upto = Nth1.
nth1_once_else_0_thaw_([H|T], Elem, Upto, Nth1) :-
    % Wait for possible comparison
    when(
        (?=(H, Elem) ; nonvar(Nth1)),
        nth1_once_else_0_thaw_([H|T], Elem, Upto, Nth1)
    ).

nth1_once_else_0_when_(L, Elem, Upto, Nth1) :-
    var(L),
    !,
    when(
        (nonvar(L), nonvar(Elem) ; nonvar(Nth1)),
        nth1_once_else_0_thaw_(L, Elem, Upto, Nth1)
    ).
nth1_once_else_0_when_([], _Elem, _Upto, 0).
nth1_once_else_0_when_([H|T], Elem, Upto, Nth1) :-
    when(
        (nonvar(H), nonvar(Elem) ; nonvar(Nth1)),
        nth1_once_else_0_thaw_([H|T], Elem, Upto, Nth1)
    ).

% Remainder of list does not match
nth1_once_else_0_thaw_0_(L, Elem) :-
    var(L),
    !,
    freeze(L, nth1_once_else_0_thaw_0_(L, Elem)).
nth1_once_else_0_thaw_0_([], _Elem).
nth1_once_else_0_thaw_0_([H|T], Elem) :-
    dif(H, Elem),
    freeze(T, nth1_once_else_0_thaw_0_(T, Elem)).
```

Using swi-prolog's [unit test](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section(%27packages/plunit.html%27)) ability:

```
:- begin_tests(nth1_once_else_0).

test(1) :-
    nth1_once_else_0(2, [a, b], B), B == b.
test(2) :-
    nth1_once_else_0(N, [a, b, c, d, e, f, g], a), N == 1.
test(3) :-
    nth1_once_else_0(N, [a, b, c, d, e, f, g], j), N == 0.
test(4) :-
    nth1_once_else_0(N, [a, b, c, d, e, f, g], b), N == 2.
test(5) :-
    nth1_once_else_0(N, [], a), N == 0.
test(6) :-
    nth1_once_else_0(N, [], _), N == 0.
test(7) :-
    nth1_once_else_0(N, [a, b, c, a, b, c], a), N == 1.
test(8) :-
    \+ nth1_once_else_0(6, [a, b, c, a, b, c], c).
test(9) :-
    nth1_once_else_0(N, L, b), L = [a, b], N == 2.
test(10) :-
    \+ nth1_once_else_0(0, [a, b], b).
test(11) :-
    nth1_once_else_0(N, [a, b, c, a], a), N == 1.
test(12) :-
    nth1_once_else_0(N, [a, b, c], d), N == 0.
test(13) :-
    nth1_once_else_0(N, [a, b], X), X = b, N == 2.
test(14) :-
    nth1_once_else_0(N, L, X), L = [a, b|_], X = b, N == 2.
test(15) :-
    nth1_once_else_0(N, L, X), L = [a, b|_], N = 2, X == b.
test(16) :-
    nth1_once_else_0(N, L, X), L = [a, b|_], X = z, N = 0.
test(17) :-
    L = [a, a], nth1_once_else_0(1, L, a), \+ nth1_once_else_0(2, L, a).
test(18) :-
    nth1_once_else_0(N, L, X), L = [a, b|_], L = [a,b,c], N = 0, \+ X = a.
test(19) :-
    nth1_once_else_0(N, L, X), L = [a, b|_], X = z, L = [a, b], N == 0.
test(20) :-
    nth1_once_else_0(N, L, X), nth1(2, L, b), nth1(1, L, a), X = z, L = [a, b], N == 0.
test(21) :-
    nth1_once_else_0(N, L, X), nth1(2, L, b), nth1(1, L, a), L = [a, b], X = a, N == 1.
test(22) :-
    nth1_once_else_0(N, L, X), X = a, nth1(2, L, b), nth1(1, L, a), N == 1.
test(23) :-
    nth1_once_else_0(N, L, X), X = b,  nth1(2, L, b), nth1(1, L, a), N == 2.
test(24) :-
    nth1_once_else_0(3, L, c), nth1(3, L, C), C == c.
test(25) :-
    nth1_once_else_0(3, L, C), C = c, nth1(3, L, Z), Z == c.
test(26) :-
    nth1_once_else_0(N, L, c),  N = 3, nth1(N, L, C), C == c.
test(27) :-
    nth1_once_else_0(N, L, C), C = c, N = 3, nth1(N, L, Z), Z == c.
test(28) :-
    nth1_once_else_0(N, [a, b, c|_], c), N == 3.
test(29) :-
    \+ nth1_once_else_0(3, [_, _], z).
test(30) :-
    nth1_once_else_0(N, [-_, -_], +_), N == 0.
test(31) :-
    nth1_once_else_0(N, L, X), nth1(2, L, b), nth1(1, L, a), X = a, N == 1.
test(32) :-
    nth1_once_else_0(N, L, f(b)), L = [f(Z)|T], Z = g(_), T = [f(B)|_], B = b, N == 2.
test(33) :-
    nth1_once_else_0(N, L, f(a)), L = [f(A)|_], A = a, N == 1.
test(34) :-
    nth1_once_else_0(N, L, f(b)), L = [f(_)|_], N = 2, nth1(2, L, B), B == f(b).

:- end_tests(nth1_once_else_0).
```

Result:

```
?- run_tests.
% All 34 tests passed
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! This answer meets all the requirements and is as well not having the problem which false pointed out with my previous solution. Because of that I am giving you the accepted answer. Can you maybe explain the `when(nonvar(H) ...` part? I am not familiar with how this predicate works.

Comment: This whole thing is way more complicated than I thought. Thanks for your work!

Comment: Updated. It passes my tests.

Comment: Updated again, to pass the 27 tests.

Comment: Very complex, and still weak: `?- nth1_once_else_0(Nth, [-_,-_], +_).` should fail immediately.

Comment: Simplified. Passes 29 tests, including `nth1_once_else_0(3, [_, _], z)`

Comment: Fixed more bugs. Passes 31 tests, including `nth1_once_else_0(Nth, [-_,-_], +_)`

Answer (score 5):

**Note**: This solution yields every index where Item is found upon backtracking and unifies `Index` with `0` *only* when no item unifies with the target item, and is not exactly what OP has now explicitly stated in his requirements.

```
item_index(Item, L, Index):-
  item_index(L, Item, 1, Index).
  
item_index([], _, _, 0).
item_index([Item|L], Item, CurIndex, Index):-
  item_index1(L, Item, CurIndex, Index).
item_index([CurItem|L], Item, CurIndex, Index):-
  dif(CurItem, Item),
  succ(CurIndex, CurIndex1),
  item_index(L, Item, CurIndex1, Index).

item_index1(_, _, Index, Index).
item_index1(L, Item, CurIndex, Index):-
  succ(CurIndex, CurIndex1),
  item_index2(L, Item, CurIndex1, Index).

item_index2([Item|L], Item, CurIndex, Index):-
  item_index1(L, Item, CurIndex, Index).
item_index2([CurItem|L], Item, CurIndex, Index):-
  dif(CurItem, Item),
  succ(CurIndex, CurIndex1),
  item_index2(L, Item, CurIndex1, Index).
```

---

Explanation:

This answer goes through different procedures to maintain the state of whether any solution has been already found. So when traversing the list in `item_index/4` there has been no match. After the first match (and upon every further match) `item_index1/4` is called which will unify `Index` with the current index and upon backtracking continue traversing the list in `item_index2/4`.

When there are no more items to traverse it will unify Index with 0 only if there has been no previous matches (this is done in the first clause of `item_index/4`).

Sample runs:

```
?- item_index(A, [a,b,c,d,a,b,c], X).
A = a,
X = 1 ;
A = a,
X = 5 ;
A = b,
X = 2 ;
A = b,
X = 6 ;
A = c,
X = 3 ;
A = c,
X = 7 ;
A = d,
X = 4 ;
X = 0,
dif(A, a),
dif(A, c),
dif(A, b),
dif(A, a),
dif(A, d),
dif(A, c),
dif(A, b).

?- item_index(d, [a,b,c], X).
X = 0.    

?- item_index(A, [a,b,a], X).
A = a,
X = 1 ;
A = a,
X = 3 ;
A = b,
X = 2 ;
X = 0,
dif(A, a),
dif(A, a),
dif(A, b).

?- item_index(a, [a,b,C], X).
X = 1 ;
C = a,
X = 3 ;
false.
```

Comment: This works for me, but if I ask the query `?- item_index(a, [a, b, c, d, a], N).` I get `yes. N = 1` and `no.` as an answer. And I am having quite some problems to really understand the code. Can you maybe explain your thaught process a bit so that I can understand the code a little bit better?

Comment: Your query should yield `N = 1` and then upon backtracking (press `;`) should yield `N = 5`. Pressing `;` again would give you false as there are no more solutions.

Comment: @DavidKrell: edited answer to add explanation of how the code works

Comment: It should only find the first appearance of an element. So the query `?- item_index(a, [a,b,c,d,a], 5).` should give `no.` as an answer.

Comment: As stated in the the first paragraph, this answer yields every index where Item is found. If you want to commit to the first answer then you may change `item_index/3` to `item_index(Item, L, Index):-  item_index(L, Item, 1, FirstIndex),  !,  Index=FirstIndex.` though this may give incorrect results for non ground `Item`/`L`.

Comment: But now it still gives `yes` for the following query: `?- item_index(a,[a,b,c,a],4)`. But it shouldn't give `yes` because the a at index 4 is not the first a. I added the requirements in my question, so everyone can make sure their answer meets them.

Comment: Have you changed `item_index/3` to the code I provided in my last comment ? It should five you `false` with that change. I understand you now have modified your question to add explicit requirements. This answer may help others with similar but not exactly the same requirements as yours. I will add a note at the beginning of this answer to make it clear

Comment: How does this meet the requirements of the bounty? Sounds like @false wanted something very different to the OP. E.g. `item_index(E, L, I).` just goes off to infinity, and continues going after a match is found. `item_index(E, L, I), I = 0.` goes off to infinity after the first solution.

Answer (score 3):

Two pure solutions using the library `reif`:

```
first_index(E0, Es, N) :-
    first_index_(E0, Es, 0, N).

first_index_(_, [], _, none).
first_index_(E0, [E|Es], I0, N) :-
    if_(
        E0 = E,
        N = some(I0),
        (   succ(I0, I),
            first_index_(E0, Es, I, N)
        )
    ).

index(E0, Es, none) :-
    maplist(dif(E0), Es).
index(E0, Es, some(I)) :-
    nth0(I, Es, E0).
```

This query succeeds deterministically:

```
?- L = [a,a], N = some(0), first_index(a, L, N).
   L = "aa", N = some(0).
```

This query fails:

```
?- L = [a,a], N = some(1), first_index(a, L, N).
   false.
```

While with `index/3`:

```
?- L = [a,a], index(a, L, some(0)), index(a, L, some(1)).
   L = "aa".
```

The question:

```
find_first(E, Es, N) :-
    first_index(E, Es, I),
    conversion(I, N).

find(E, Es, N) :-
    index(E, Es, I),
    conversion(I, N).

conversion(none, 0).
conversion(some(I), N) :-
    succ(I, N).
```

---

For now I don't have a better name.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Can you maybe explain the queries more? If I give the following query: `first_index(a, [b, a, c], N)` the answer is `no.`  But it should give `yes. N = 2.` Or how should I formulate the query so that it gives me the right answer?

Comment: oh okay I'll try to do that. But until now I never worked with libraries in PROLOG I just used my own predicates and recursion and maybe there is a way to solve this problem withou using libraries?

Comment: If I copy and paste it and I give it the following query: `?- first_index(a, [a,b,c], N)` I get an error stating that the procedure `if_/3` is not known. If I give it the following query: `?- index(a, [a,b,c],N)` I get `N = some(0)`. But it should be `N = 1`.

Comment: I am using SWI Prolog (AMD64, Multi-threaded, version 9.0.0)

Comment: [`reif`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/meditans/reif/master/prolog/reif.pl), `:- use_module(reif)`.

Comment: It really would be a good idea to use `0` and `nth1/3` instead, such that it conforms to OP's requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Using a descriptive predicate name:

```
nth1_once_else_0(Elem, Lst, Nth1) :-
    % Start at element 1
    nth1_once_else_0_(Lst, Elem, 1, Nth1),
    % Stop after finding 1 solution
    !.
% Otherwise, succeed with 0
nth1_once_else_0(_Elem, _Lst, 0).

% Using Upto and Nth1 arguments, rather than unnecessary & slow recursion
nth1_once_else_0_([Elem|_], Elem, Nth1, Nth1).
nth1_once_else_0_([_|T], Elem, Upto, Nth1) :-
    % Loop through the list elements
    Upto1 is Upto + 1,
    nth1_once_else_0_(T, Elem, Upto1, Nth1).
```

Results in swi-prolog:

```
?- nth1_once_else_0(c, [a, b, c, a, b, c], Nth1).
Nth1 = 3.

?- nth1_once_else_0(z, [a, b, c, a, b, c], Nth1).
Nth1 = 0.

?- nth1_once_else_0(Char, [a, b, c, a, b, c], Nth1).
Char = a,
Nth1 = 1.

?- nth1_once_else_0(Char, [a, b, c, a, b, c], 2).
Char = b.

?- nth1_once_else_0(b, [a, b, c, a, b, c], 3).
false.
```

Below is an improved version:

```
nth1_once_else_0(Elem, Lst, Nth1) :-
    % Start at element 1
    nth1_once_else_0_(Lst, Elem, 1, Nth1),
    % Stop after finding 1 solution
    !.
% Otherwise, succeed with 0
nth1_once_else_0(_Elem, _Lst, 0).

% Using Upto and Nth1 arguments, rather than unnecessary & slow recursion
nth1_once_else_0_([Elem|_], Elem, Upto, Nth1) :-
    % Found first match on element
    !,
    Upto = Nth1.
nth1_once_else_0_([_|T], Elem, Upto, Nth1) :-
    % Loop through the list elements
    Upto1 is Upto + 1,
    nth1_once_else_0_(T, Elem, Upto1, Nth1).
```

... to prevent going past the first element match:

```
?- nth1_once_else_0(c, [a, b, c, a, b, c], 6).
false.

?- nth1_once_else_0(c, [a, b, c, a, b, c], Nth1).
Nth1 = 3.

?- nth1_once_else_0(z, [a, b, c, a, b, c], Nth1).
Nth1 = 0.
```

Comment: Why a descriptive name, if your definition is non-relational?

Comment: @false Where is the law stated that non-relational definitions can't have reasonably descriptive names? What better predicate name do you suggest?

Comment: The question is rather why should this definition be non-relational at all?

Comment: @false what exactly is the problem with brebs answer? It works fine for  me. Is it just the name  of the predicate?

Comment: `?- nth1_once_else_0(c, [a,b,c,a,b, c],Nth1), Nth1 = 6. false.` but `?- Nth1 = 6, nth1_once_else_0(c, [a,b,c,a,b, c],Nth1).` succeeds. So it is non-relational.

Comment: @false Added fixed version.

Comment: Now, `?- nth1_once_else_0(1,L,N),L=[0,1].
   false.` but `?- L=[0,1],nth1_once_else_0(1,L,N).
   L = [0,1], N = 2.`

Comment: `?- nth1_once_else_0(a, [b,a], 0).` succeds but it shouldn't because a is in the list.

Comment: @false I think you you're asking for the impossible. `p(a, L, N)` cannot provide a *single* solution as to which element in the uninstantiated list L is the first being `a`. For this to be possible, `N` must be supplied. Or allow multiple solutions, as with `memberd`.

Comment: Currently, there are 1+(1+1) = 3 relational solutions....